# Tense agreement in a compound sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sequence-of-tenses

Which sentence is correct, and can I use such a sentence is narrative reports?

> Sports **have become** part of school’s time table, and teachers **give** time to children for play and sports in school timing.
>
> Sports **have become** part of school’s time table, and teachers **gave** time to children for play and sports in school timing.

Comment: @choster: the first one has "give," the second has "gave." Took me a while to find it as well.

Comment: @sumelic Thanks. Neither sentence is idiomatic English, though.

Answer (score 1):

*gave* is the past tense, so it should only be used if teachers no longer give children time for play and sports. If the practice is ongoing, the present tense *give* should be used.